# Sendmail: how to reject a specific plussed address

Tags: sendmail

I'm on lots of mailing lists, with an address of `list+detail@foo.com`, where `detail` is specific to the list. My MTA is sendmail, with no specific virtusertable entry for these plussed addresses. The plussed addresses go without modification to dovecot, and on to my mail client, where they're sorted.

Problem: what do I do if `list+bar@foo.com` starts getting lots of spam? Can I reject this one specific plussed address at sendmail? I can't find a way to do this with either `virtusertable` or `aliases`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want virtusertable entry similar to the one below

```
list+bar@foo.com   error:nouser 550 No such user here
```

---

[virtusrtable](https://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/features.html#virtusertable)  can reject envelope recipient with custom error message

> ```
> jax@bar.com   error:5.7.0:550 Address invalid
> ```
>
> mail to jax@bar.com will also have a RFC 1893 compliant error code 5.7.0.

[virtusertable](https://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/features.html#virtusertable)  handles elebarate sequence of lookups for plusses address

> The username from the original address is passed as %1 allowing:
>
> ```
> @foo.org  %1@example.com
> ```
>
> meaning someone@foo.org will be sent to someone@example.com. Additionally, if the local part consists of "user+detail" then "detail" is passed as %2 and "+detail" is passed as %3 when a match against user+* is attempted, so entries like
>
> ```
> old+*@foo.org new+%2@example.com
> gen+*@foo.org %2@example.com
> +*@foo.org    %1%3@example.com
> X++@foo.org   Z%3@example.com
> @bar.org  %1%3
> ```

Comment: For some reason I thought that 'nouser'/etc wouldn't work for plussed addresses. I've just tried it, and it does - thanks!